# why urlencode a formdata then encode it again with utf-8, what's logic here?

Tags: python, http, encoding, urlencode

I was reading a tutorial and find this piece of code really confusing.

```
from urllib import request, parse

print('Login to somesite.com...') 
email = input('Email: ') 
passwd = input('Password: ') 
login_data = parse.urlencode([
    ('username', email),
    ('password', passwd),
    ('entry', 'mweibo'),
    ('client_id', ''),
    ('savestate', '1'),
    ('ec', ''),
    ('pagerefer', 'a referer') ])

req = request.Request('somesite.com') 
req.add_header('Origin', 'a origin') 
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/6.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25') 
req.add_header('Referer', 'a referer')

with request.urlopen(req, data=login_data.encode('utf-8')) as f:
    print('Status:', f.status, f.reason)
    for k, v in f.getheaders():
        print('%s: %s' % (k, v))
    print('Data:', f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

what does `urlencode` do here and what does `login_data.encode('utf-8'))` do next?

Comment: _"what does urlencode do here"_ Have you read [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)? Have you looked at its output (`print(login_data)`)? Does the tutorial you're reading not explain any of this code? You have plenty of ways to figure this out.

Comment: The output of `urlencode` is a percent-encoded ASCII text string, and that needs to be converted to a bytes string to use it as the data of a POST request. You could just encode it as ASCII bytes, but there's no harm using UTF-8, since UTF-8 preserves plain ASCII. However, the last line is a bit of a worry. As in your previous question, that code is assuming that the returned data is UTF-8, it should check that, or at least wrap the code containing the `.decode('utf-8')` call in an appropriate `try...except` so it can recover fom a decoding error.

Comment: @Rawing Oh, you may misunderstand my question. In some way I understand why url is need to be encoded (as the RFC mentioned blablabla). But I am not quite sure about why the formdata get urlencoded, that's my confusion part. I've checked the doc more and searched more than once for sure.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for your patience. Your answers help me a lot :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While they have the same name, they perform different kind of operation:

- URL encoding is used to adapt some data to be sent as part of an URL. URL have some restriction on the kind of characters, they cannot contain spaces or @ or other special characters, therefore they must be converted to not be confused (for example spaces get turn into `%20`). In `parse`, it basically takes a list of tuples `(left, right)` and creates a string with a list of `name=value` separated by `&`. To clarify, here is an example

Code:

```
parse.urlencode([
    (name1,value1), (name2, value2)
])
```

Result:

```
name1=value1&name2=value2
```

- UTF-8 encoding is used to map the characters to a sequence of byte. Char must be represented as byte (as everything else) and various mapping exist. UTF-8 is one of the most used because it is able to map a wide variety of characters while keeping most used ones short.

Comment: yes. I can possibly understand why url uses urlencode (much same as you mentioned) . But why urlencode the form data? Can't I just encode it into utf-8 bytes directly?

Comment: ulrencoding is the standard procedure to create a query string that contains the data for a GET or POST form, it is needed to allow the other side to get back the name/value pair. UTF-8 is a lower level encoding to assure the right interpretation of the byte stream.